# Nginx proxy pass not resolving

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, proxypass

I'm new to Nginx and I'm trying to define locations to match certain patterns.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, but this what I figured out so far.

**Requirements**

| Location | Proxy Pass |
| --- | --- |
| /api/cars/carID?queryString | https://myapi/api/cars/carID?queryString |
| /api/cars/carID/model?queryString | https://myapi/api/cars/carID/model?queryString |
| /api/cars/carID/anythingElse?queryString | **Shouldn't be proxied** |
| /api/cars/carID/model/anythingElse?queryString | **Shouldn't be proxied** |

**Attempted**

```
location ~*/api/cars/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/model$ {
   proxy_pass https://myapi/api/cars/$1/model;
   
}
location ~*/api/cars/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ 
    proxy_pass https://myapi/api/cars/$1;
   
}
```

**Update**

Getting the following error message in the ngnix error logs

> no resolver defined to resolve myapi

It is worth mentioning that I'm running nginx inside docker container.
I examined the `resolv.conf` and it looks like the DNS requests are being forwarded to the host (Windows machine).

Comment: `~*/api/cars/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/model/` doesn't match the requirements, it should be `~* ^/api/cars/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/model$`. There is a `$` in the wrong place and a trailing `/`. The URL `https://myapi/api/car/$1/model` does not match the requirements - should that be `cars` and not `car`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I updated the configurations to match what you suggested. An error showing up in the logs `*2 no resolver defined to resolve myapi`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pointers to help you with your development, though my answer may not satisfy every one of your requirements:

**RESOLVING DOCKER DNS HOST NAMES**

During developoment you can use the Docker embedded DNS server to resolve URLs. So if you have a deployed API like this in Docker Compose:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
    hostname: nginx-internal
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  api:
    image: my-api:1.0.0
    hostname: api-internal
```

Then specifying the Docker internal DNS server will ensure that DNS is resolved correctly for other Docker containers. Further info in [this article](https://transang.me/dns-server-in-docker-container/).

```
location ~ ^/ {
  resolver 127.0.0.11;
  proxy_pass http://api-internal$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

**RESOLVING HOST COMPUTER DNS HOST NAMES**

Sometimes you may want to route through NGINX in Docker back to an API running on the host computer. On the host you might define a custom host name in the `hosts` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 api.example.com
```

You can then point NGINX running in Docker to the local API like this:

```yaml
nginx:
  image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
  hostname: nginx-internal
  extra_hosts:
  - api.example.com:host-gateway
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

```
location ~ ^/ {
  resolver 127.0.0.11;
  proxy_pass http://api.example.com$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your api server host `myapi` is not resolved from your nginx container.

Your api server should either:

1. Run in a container named `myapi` and have the same network as your nginx container (if using`docker-compose` all containers defined are part of the same network).
2. Have a proper DNS which can be resolved on the internet or your private net

Comment: Can you clarify `proper DNS`? As I mentioned,  I examined the `resolv.conf` in the nginx container. DNS requests are being forwarded to the host (Windows machine)

Comment: resolve.conf is probably configured to use some service on the host. You probably have no need to touch this areas. Proper DNS, as in a domain you bought from AWS or whoever and can be accessed anywhere on the internet. I think that in your case you need to check the docker container name and see that nginx and your api container are on the same docker network